# quantize an analog signal in matlab

Tags: matlab

Sample and quantize the signals `y1= sin(2000πt) + cos(2000πt) with Ts = 0.1 ms and for 0 ≤ t ≤ 2 ms`. Where Ts is the sampling interval and the ADC has 8, 16, and 32 uniform quantization levels.

I can't figure out how to go about quantizing the signal in `Matlab`. I can create the signal but I am stuck on the quantizing part.

```
t=(0:.00001:.002);

x=sin(2000*pi*t)+cos(2000*pi*t);

plot(t,x);'
```

Where do I go from here? I am fairly new to `Matlab`.

Comment: Could you write a function that breaks up your full scale range into N buckets and returns the quantized output level for a given sample?  Then call this for all 20 of your discrete samples.

Comment: Look up function `quantiz` in Matlab for both a solution and a good explanation of the process.

Comment: What is the analog input range of the ADC? ±1.5 V? By the way, be careful because if `Ts` is 0.1 ms you should use `0.0001` instead of `0.00001`

Comment: for example, `xq = int16(8*x)`

Comment: Note that your sampling interval seems wrong, from the problem definition you should have 21 samples, not 201

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code inspired from [matlab quantize](https://www.mathworks.com/help/comm/ug/quantization.html). The partition/codebook is written for 3-bit / 8 levels.

```
Ts=0.0001;
t=0:.00001:20*Ts;
sig=sin(2000*pi*t)+cos(2000*pi*t);
maxsig=max(sig); %signal max
interv=2*maxsig/(2^3-1); %interval length for 8 levels resolution
u=maxsig+interv;
partition = [-maxsig:interv:maxsig]; 
codebook = [-maxsig:interv:u]; 
[index,quants] = quantiz(sig,partition,codebook); % Quantize.
plot(t,sig,'-',t,quants,'-');
legend('Original signal','Quantized signal');
```